# Memory Issue While Fetching large data using Stored Procedure.

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, memory, out-of-memory, spring-jdbc

I simply need to call MySql Stored Procedure using Hibernate and write a file based on it. 
But there are 0.3 to 0.4 million rows return from stored procedure and they are pretty big.

**Here is my code snippet**

```
try {
session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL MyStoredProcedure();");
List<Object[]> result = query.list();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(session!= null) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

**and error message**

```
Exception in thread "ContainerBackgroundProcessor[StandardEngine[Catalina]]" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize0(Native Method)
at java.io.UnixFileSystem.canonicalize(UnixFileSystem.java:172)
at java.io.File.getCanonicalPath(File.java:576)
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.file(FileDirContext.java:806)
at org.apache.naming.resources.FileDirContext.doGetAttributes(FileDirContext.java:430)
at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.getAttributes(BaseDirContext.java:1089)
at org.apache.naming.resources.BaseDirContext.getAttributes(BaseDirContext.java:1042)
at org.apache.naming.resources.ProxyDirContext.getAttributes(ProxyDirContext.java:884)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.modified(WebappClassLoader.java:984)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.modified(WebappLoader.java:501)
at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappLoader.backgroundProcess(WebappLoader.java:421)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1350)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1537)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1547)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1526)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
```

After investigating a bit at work I noticed I have to use setFetchSize() and setMaxResults() in my code.Like

```
try {
session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL MyStoredProcedure();");
query.setFetchSize(1000);
query.setFirstResult(lowerLimit);
query.setMaxResults(upperLimit);
List<Object[]> result = query.list();
} catch (HibernateException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    if(session!= null) {
        session.flush();
        session.clear();
    }
}
```

But this time I am getting another error. Following is error message

```
org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:67)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:43)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2216)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.listIgnoreQueryCache(Loader.java:2104)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.list(Loader.java:2099)
    at org.hibernate.loader.custom.CustomLoader.list(CustomLoader.java:289)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.listCustomQuery(SessionImpl.java:1695)
    at org.hibernate.impl.AbstractSessionImpl.list(AbstractSessionImpl.java:142)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SQLQueryImpl.list(SQLQueryImpl.java:152)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.doInvokeMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:710)
    at org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.support.HandlerMethodInvoker.invokeHandlerMethod(HandlerMethodInvoker.java:167)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:414)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.annotation.AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.handle(AnnotationMethodHandlerAdapter.java:402)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:771)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:716)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:647)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:552)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:722)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:243)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:224)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:169)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:168)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:98)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:927)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:407)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:987)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:579)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:309)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:636)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'limit 100000, 120000' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor50.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:532)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:406)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:381)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1030)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3515)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3447)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1951)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2101)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2554)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:1761)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeQuery(PreparedStatement.java:1912)
    at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.NewProxyPreparedStatement.executeQuery(NewProxyPreparedStatement.java:76)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.getResultSet(AbstractBatcher.java:186)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.getResultSet(Loader.java:1787)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQuery(Loader.java:674)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doQueryAndInitializeNonLazyCollections(Loader.java:236)
    at org.hibernate.loader.Loader.doList(Loader.java:2213)
```

So how can I resolve this issue? Please help.

Comment: How about lowering the limit, does that help ?

Comment: @Aviram I am starting limit from 1000 to 20000 it will fetch data up to 100000 but after this it is giving me Error

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loading everything in memory, do it like you would do in JDBC: scroll through the results:

```
query = session.createSQLQuery("CALL MyStoredProcedure();");
ScrollableResults results = query.scroll();
while (results.next()) {
    Object[] row = results.get();
    // TODO write the row into the file
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick response I tried your solution but it is now taking lots of time and i got following error now java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Comment: Actually I am trying to add object value in form Bean and the adding that bean into Array List

Comment: You're trying to load a huge amount of data in memory. Either increase the memory settings of your JVM, or choose another strategy. Memory is a limited resource. You can't load an arbistrary amount of data in memory and hope everything runs fine. You told in your question that you wanted to write the data to a file. Then do it as I show in my question. This will ensure you only have some rows in memory. The rest of the rows will either still to be read from the database cursor, or already written to the file.

Comment: I am using org.apache.poi API for writing file so basically what I am trying to do is get all records in Array List of Beans and then add this list in Spring ModelMap and write into file.